# Why does an object log `[object Object]` when called with `console.log`?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm honestly not very sure how to format this, as I'm putting a long piece of code in here, so I'll be checking this frequently to clear up any confusion.

The code in question is as follows:

```js
const menu = {
  _courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains: [],
    desserts: []
  },
  get appetizers() {
    this._courses.appetizers;
  },
  set appetizers(appetizerIn) {
    this._courses.appetizers = appetizerIn;
  },
  get mains() {
    this._courses.mains;
  },
  set mains(mainIn) {
    this._courses.mains = mainIn;
  },
  get desserts() {
    this._courses.desserts;
  },
  set desserts(dessertIn) {
    this._courses.desserts = dessertIn;
  },
  get courses() {
    return {
      appetizers: this.appetizers,
      mains: this.mains,
      desserts: this.desserts
    }
  },
  addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
    const dish = {
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice
    }
    this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  },
  getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
    const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
    const dishNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
    return dishes[dishNum];
  },
  generateRandomMeal() {
    const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    const main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    const dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    const totalPrice = appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price;
    console.log(appetizer)
    return `Appetizer: ${appetizer}
Main: ${main}
Dessert: ${dessert}
Total Price: ${totalPrice}`;
  },
}
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 1, 1)
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 2, 2)
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 3, 3)
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 1, 1)
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 2, 2)
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 3, 3)
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 1, 1)
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 2, 2)
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 3, 3)
const meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```

The specific part of the code that I returns the string to be logged to the console is

```
generateRandomMeal() {
    const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    const main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    const dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    const totalPrice = appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price;
    console.log(appetizer)
    return Appetizer: ${appetizer}
Main: ${main}
Dessert: ${dessert}
Total Price: ${totalPrice}`;
  },
```

What I expected it to print to the console was `[ *key*: *value*, *key2*: *value2* ]` but instead it printed `[ object Object ]`. The reason I know the object is defined is that when I replace `console.log(appetizer)` with `console.log(appetizer.name)` it prints the correct name.

Comment: use JSON.stringify()

Comment: Why? beacuse the programmer who wrote it, did it this way... :)

----- A good article:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-log-an-object-to-the-console-in-javascript-7b995c56af5a

------ And in SO, several other similar questions: https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+does+an+object+log+%60%5Bobject+Object%5D%60+when+called+with+%60console.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both browser and nodejs environment, running `console.log(appetizer)` produces:

```js
{
  "name": 3,
  "price": 3
}
```

---

`[object Object]` is only produced by running `console.log(meal)`

```
Appetizer: [object Object]
Main: [object Object]
Dessert: [object Object]
Total Price: 6
```

And that's normal because the objects are implicitly cast to string. These are equivalent:

```js
const obj = { a: 1 }
console.log('Hello: ' + obj)
console.log('Hello: ' + obj.toString())
console.log(`Hello: ${obj}`)
```

If you want your string to contain object's JSON reprenstation use `JSON.stringify`:

```js
const obj = { a: 1 }
const s = 'Hello: ' + JSON.stringify(obj); /// or JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2); with 2 spacing
console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if appetizer is a JSON object, you can simply use JSON.stringify(object).

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(appetizer))
```

While ***console.log()*** will work for objects, there is a method specifically meant for displaying objects to the console called **console.dir()**.

```
console.dir(appetizer)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. I am amazed how it got upvotes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JSON.stringify()`, which turns the object into a string that `console.log` will then print out.

When confronted with an object, `console.log` won't dive into the object and print everything out for you.

It simply recognizes it as an object and logs `[Object object]`.

So for your example, you need to do :

```
return `Appetizer: ${JSON.stringify(appetizer)};
        Main: ${JSON.stringify(main)}
        Dessert: ${JSON.stringify(dessert)}
        Total Price: ${JSON.stringify(totalPrice)}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**

`[object Object]` is the default string representation of custom objects. You can override this behavior by implementing your own `toString` method, or by adding a getter property with the well-known symbol `@@toStringTag`. `console.log` is not part of the ECMAScript specification, and in most cases will try to print something more meaningful than `[object Object]`.

**Details**

JavaScript provides default string representations of objects of the form `[object <Tag>]`.

Some built-in objects, such as `Function` and `Date` override the `Object#toString` method, but we can still get to the default string representation by calling `Object#toString` on those objects. If we review the output, a pattern emerges!

```js
const toString = Function.prototype.call.bind({}.toString)

// Instances
console.log(toString({}))              // [object Object]
console.log(toString(undefined))       // [object Undefined] ¹
console.log(toString(null))            // [object Null] ¹
console.log(toString(/foo/))           // [object RegExp]
console.log(toString(true))            // [object Boolean]
console.log(toString(''))              // [object String]
console.log(toString(new ArrayBuffer)) // [object ArrayBuffer]
console.log(toString(1))               // [object Number]
console.log(toString(Symbol()))        // [object Symbol]

// Constructor functions
console.log(toString(Number))          // [object Function]    
console.log(toString(Date))            // [object Function]
console.log(toString(RegExp))          // [object Function]

// Namespace objects:
console.log(toString(Math))            // [object Math]
console.log(toString(JSON))            // [object JSON]
console.log(toString(Atomics))         // [object Atomics]
console.log(toString(Intl))            // [object Object] ²
console.log(toString(Reflect))         // [object Object] ²
```

Custom objects inherit the `toString` method of `Object.prototype`, but you can override it:

```js
const o = { dish: 'Fish & Chips', toString() { return JSON.stringify(this) } }
console.log('' + o) // { "dish": "Fish & Chips" }
```

...but if you directly call `Object#toString` against your custom object, you will still get `[object Object]`. You can change this by defining a property with the key of the well-known symbol @@toStringTag:

```js
const o = { get [Symbol.toStringTag]() { return 'Bubblegum!' } }
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(o)) // '[object Bubblegum!]'
```

¹ These values might look strange, but I think they arise from the specification saying that the output of `Object#toString` should simply be `[object <string tag>]`. For `null` and `undefined`, the string tags are `Null` and `Undefined` respectively, giving the values `[object Null]` and `[object Undefined]`.

² Note that the inconsistency of the value emitted by the `toString` operation on the `Intl` and `Reflect` built-in objects was, the last time I looked (early 2020), an open point of discussion in TC-39, and probably results from different teams implementing those APIs.